# How to draw a 2D array with indices on top?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays

Right now, I have the code below that makes this

[image]

However, I'd like to do two things. One, change the indices to be on over the boxes instead of under. Two, add more rows so that this is a 2D array, hopefully with different amount of spacing in between the rows and columns.

Basically, I want this but where every row is different.
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{index}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setcounter{index}{0}
    \coordinate (s) at (0,0);
    \foreach \num in {3, 1, 4, 1, 5}{
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] at (s) {\num};
      \node at ($(s)-(0,0.5)$) {\theindex};
      \stepcounter{index}
      \coordinate (s) at ($(s) + (1,0)$);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:testArray}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just a part of image for the case if the node contents is prescribed. with use of matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\usepackage[active,floats, tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={minimum size=8mm},
             column sep=4mm]
{
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4   \\
};
\matrix (n) [below=-3mm of m,
             matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=8mm},
             column sep=4mm,
             row sep=2mm]
{
9 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 5   \\
8 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 5   \\
7 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 5   \\
6 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 5   \\
5 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 5   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:testArray}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
inspired by [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi)  answer and his [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386476/problem-using-pgfmatrixcurrentrow-for-labels-in-matrix-of-nodes-style-definition) question. now with one matrix and indices as labels of nodes in the first row::

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix [matrix of nodes,
         nodes = {draw,  minimum size = 2ex},
         column sep=1ex, row sep=1ex,
         row 1/.style={execute at begin cell= {|[label=\pgfmathparse{int(\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn-1)}\pgfmathresult]|}}
         ]
{
9 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 5   \\
8 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 5   \\
7 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 5   \\
6 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 5   \\
5 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 5   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This solution is similar to Zarko's one, but uses only one `matrix`. The first row is used for column enumerating and all other rows are the real matrix contents. As we want all nodes with border except for the first row, a special style has been defined: `row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}}`.

Distance between columns and row is declared with `col sep` and `row sep`, but it can be changed with an special command: `[value]` in first row elements or after end of row declaration: `\\`. In following code there are some examples, two of them just to show its effect, but `[-3mm]` after first row has been used to compensate the size of first row nodes and make them look like a label.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1em]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=8mm},
             column sep=3mm,
             row sep=2mm,
             row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}}]
{
0 & 1 & 2 &[5mm] 3 & 4   \\[-3mm]
9 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 5   \\
8 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 5   \\
7 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 5   \\[3mm]
6 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 5   \\
5 & 6 & 0 & 2 & 5   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]