# Problem using \pgfmatrixcurrentrow for labels in matrix of nodes style definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

Following code shows four different ways of adding a label with its column and row value for certain nodes in a `matrix` or `matrix of nodes`. The problem is that the fourth way (commented in code) doesn't work. Compilation finishes with error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\pgfutil@g@addto@macro #1#2->\begingroup 
                                         \pgfutil@toks@ \expandafter {#1#2}\...
l.37    D\\

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Could you explain me why? Are `matrix of nodes` limited respect `matrix`?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (a) 
{
    \node[draw, 
        label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow, 
        label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn] {A};\\
};

\matrix (b) [right = 1mm of a, 
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes = {draw}] 
{
    |[label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow, 
        label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]| B\\
};

\matrix (c) [right = 3mm of b.south east, matrix anchor=south west,
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes = {draw}] 
{
    C\\
};
\node also [label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow, 
        label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn] (c-1-1) {};

%This labelling way doesn't work. 
%\matrix (d) [right= of c,
%       matrix of nodes,
%       nodes={draw, 
%           label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow, 
%           label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}] 
%{
%   D\\
%};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is expanded too early at the time of reading `nodes`. `execute at begin cell` can be an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as noted [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) on his comment above, the `executes at begin cell` is solution for your fourth (d) example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (d) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=2ex},
             execute at begin cell= {|[label=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn, % <---
                                       label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow]|} % <---
             ]
{
    D\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for translating @percusse's comment to some code. I see that `execute at begin cell` has to be applied outside nodes styles. Although it's not in the original question, could you extend the solution to label top row and left column of a 2x2 or 3x3 matrix? I've tried with three styles (corner, toprow, leftcolumn) based on your answer but as soon as two of them are applied it fails.

Comment: extension to the first row you can find in addendum to my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386406/how-to-draw-a-2d-array-with-indices-on-top, similarly you can add to the first/last column. but to the first row and column in the same time ... i need to check.

Comment: Yes, only the first row or the first column shows no problem, but both together is more difficult.

Comment: i try to make a test, if the cell is the first: `column 1/.style={\ifnum\value{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}>1
                       execute at begin cell={|[label=left:\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow]|}
                          \fi}`, but approach is to naive :-(. i got the error: ˙missing \endcsname`.

Comment: May be you are interested in this answer. It solves the second problem although not so well as I would like. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386860/1952